# SQL Date Function

Tags: sql, function, date

I may be using the wrong term (hence why I can't find it on google).

"Are there any functions or common code for Accounting Months Deliminations?"

For Example, this month started on a friday but on most accounting journals the weeks are measured by the first monday of the month so instead of having the 1st of July it would be the 4th of July. Same thing with the month end (29th instead of the 31st)

Again, I'm sure someone has created this 'wheel' before, and I can't seem to find it for the life of me.

Comment: would you call this fiscal months?

Comment: maybe, it appears in my documentation as accounting months. (I'm going to google via fiscal months to see what I find)

Comment: I'm not aware of anything out-of-the-box to do what you do, but there are various functions and routines that can be used to find the first Monday of a given month.  Presumably you could use these to prepopulate a table that would map calendar dates to their appropriate accounting month, then create a user function to the mapping live in your code.  But maybe if you give an example of what you'd like to *do*; i.e., what code you're trying to write and where you're getting stuck, I could be more helpful?

Comment: Can't create tables in the current enviroment (DBA is on vacation). I'm mostly querying a sum of sales per fiscal months. So you would be querying a Select Sum(amount) from (Area_52) where (create fancy fiscal month expression here)

If it helps any I can use either pl/sql, t-sql or teradata if you wish.

Comment: I second the use of a calendar file - it becomes useful in a whole bunch of translation setups (between ISO/Gregorian calendars and fiscal calendars).  Allows rollups, selection by random parts of the fiscal calendar ("hey, what was the 4th fiscal week of the 3rd fiscal month like, for all previous fiscal years").  Depending on need, you pre-generate the file for a number of years, and store all dates in other files as either the ISO date, or the id in the calendar file (tends to show up in star-schemas).

Comment: So, if July month begins on the 4th and ends on the 29th, what happens to sales on the 30th?  Would they get lumped into July or August?

Comment: I made an assumption and came up with an answer.  Let me know if it seems to work.  It's a great problem -- I'll probably add it to my SQL Torture Questions I use when interviewing developers.  :)

Comment: @MichaelA - our system allows users to associate multiple periods to a date. Our calendar table only defines the ending date - by definition, any date belongs to a period with no possibility that one will fall out. Yeah, we have to do a bit more work to determine *what* period(s) a date belongs to but a date will *always* belong to at least one period if it falls in the defined calendar at all.

Comment: @DaveE - Sounds like a solid solution and is very much like what I would implement myself.  I think I'd only recommend the on-the-fly answer I gave below in the "DBA is on vacation" situation where you can't build and prepopulate a table.

Answer (score 1):

The following query assumes a table, SalesTable, has a field called Amount (the value you want to sum) and a field called SaleDate (the date on which the sale occured.)  It also assumes that accounting months begin the first Monday of the month and end on the Sunday prior to the beginning of the next accounting month.

Again, I highly recommend a table-based approach to this, but if you can't modify the schema, this should do the trick in T-SQL:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN s.SaleDate < DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, DATEADD(DAY, 6 - DATEPART(DAY, s.SaleDate ),s.SaleDate )), 0)
       THEN DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, DATEADD(DAY, 6 - DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(day,-7,s.SaleDate) ),DATEADD(day,-7,s.SaleDate) )), 0)
       ELSE DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, DATEADD(DAY, 6 - DATEPART(DAY, s.SaleDate ),s.SaleDate )), 0) 
    END AccountingMonth,

 SUM(s.Amount) TotalSales

FROM SalesTable s

GROUP BY 
    CASE WHEN s.SaleDate < DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, DATEADD(DAY, 6 - DATEPART(DAY, s.SaleDate ),s.SaleDate )), 0)
       THEN DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, DATEADD(DAY, 6 - DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(day,-7,s.SaleDate) ),DATEADD(day,-7,s.SaleDate) )), 0)
       ELSE DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, DATEADD(DAY, 6 - DATEPART(DAY, s.SaleDate ),s.SaleDate )), 0) 
    END
```

Note that the AccountingMonth return field actually contains the date of the first Monday of the month.  In actual practice, you probably want to wrap this entire query in another query that reformats AccountingMonth to whatever you like... "2011-07", "2011-08", etc.

Here's how it works: This bit of code is the important part:

```
DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, DATEADD(DAY, 6 - DATEPART(DAY, s.SaleDate ),s.SaleDate )), 0)
```

It takes any date and returns the first Monday of the month in which that date occurred.  In your case, however, you have to do a little more work because a sale might have occurred in the window between the first of the month and the first Monday of the month.  The CASE statement detects that scenario and, if it's true, subtracts a week off of the date before calculating the first Monday.

Good luck!

-Michael

Comment: Reference: http://sqlandme.com/2011/05/18/how-to-get-first-monday-week-month-tsql/

Answer (score 0):

I have some code that takes in a year and month and returns the fiscal start and end dates.  Perhaps this will give you something to go by:

```
DECLARE @yr int;
DECLARE @mo int;
SELECT @yr = 2011
SELECT @mo = 7

DECLARE @FiscalMonthStartDate datetime
DECLARE @FiscalMonthEndDate datetime

DECLARE @startOfMonth datetime
DECLARE @startOfNextMonth datetime

select @startOfMonth = CAST((CAST(@yr AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(@mo AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + '01') as DATE)
select @startOfNextMonth = CAST((CAST(@yr AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST((@mo + 1) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + '01') as DATE)

SELECT @FiscalMonthStartDate =
        CASE 
            WHEN DATEPART(DW,@startOfMonth) = 0
                THEN DATEADD(DD, 1, @startOfMonth)
            ELSE
                DATEADD(DD, 8 - DATEPART(DW,@startOfMonth), @startOfMonth)
        END

SELECT @FiscalMonthEndDate =
        CASE 
            WHEN DATEPART(DW,@startOfNextMonth) = 0
                THEN DATEADD(DD, 1, @startOfNextMonth)
            ELSE
                DATEADD(DD, 8 - DATEPART(DW,@startOfNextMonth), @startOfNextMonth)
        END

-- subtract one day to get end of fiscal month (not start of next fiscal month)
SELECT @FiscalMonthEndDate = DATEADD(DD, -1, @FiscalMonthEndDate)

SELECT @FiscalMonthStartDate, @FiscalMonthEndDate
```